# Challenging data modeling problem

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I have a table that stores customer items. The table needs to reflect the following activities:

1. When a customer adds an item to his/her queue.
2. When the item is marked for shipping to the customer.
3. When the item actually ships.
4. When the item is marked for return by the customer.
5. When a return shipping label is created for the item.
6. When the item is received back from the customer.

**The work flow will be as follows:**

1. User(s) add item(s) to list.
2. Scheduled event marks items for shipping (corresponds to info point 2).
3. Employee creates shipping labels, then marks items as shipped (to info point 3)
   --- Customer receives item, customer is happy.
4. Customer marks item for return.
5. Employee creates a shipping label the item.
6. Item gets picked up and returned.

**A customer's account should show the following:**

1. Items in queue.
2. Items shipped.
3. Items marked for return (to allow customer to cancel if customer wants to keep the item for longer).

There is no value (in my scenario) for alerting the customer when an item has been marked for shipping on our end.

I initially thought of inheritance, but things have started to get out of handle quickly. I don't know if I should have a subclass for each info point. Also, some things seem like they should not be in their own subclass (items marked for shipment, and for return, seem to be "in between" classes)

**Should I be using inheritance and create a class for each information point? Or am I over complicating this?**

**Current schema**

```
items
   - id
   - typeid (in queue, shipped, etc....)
   - userid
   - itemid
   - shippedat
   - returnedat
```

I'm using mySql, and anticipate the table to be large!

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: @Konerak, I guess I would like to know if I am approaching the solution the right way, or if I am complicating things. Should I create a subclass for each piece of into I need to track, or can somethings be lumped together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need a good way to separate the items themselves from the *workflow* which applies to them. One approach could be as follows:

- Define a table of **items**, minimally containing the `userid` and `itemid`
- Define a table of **workflow states**, minimally containing an `id` and a `name` (e.g. 'processing', 'shipped')
- Define a table **linking items to workflow states**, containing a foreign key to the item's `id` and a foreign key to the state's `id`, plus metadata applicable to the given item in the given state, such as when the state was entered or started/finished, who handled or checked-off the item in that state, etc.

Now, instead of having state-specific fields such as `shippeddate` and `returneddate` on the items table, you can find that data by joining a given item to its workflow (warning: pseudocode ahead!):

```
SELECT item.id, item.userid, item_workflow.completed_date AS returned_date
FROM item
JOIN item_workflow
JOIN workflow
WHERE workflow.state = 'Returned'
```

By joining items to their workflow and filtering for specific states, you can find items that are or are not in given states, and count items per state. So to address an example from your question:

> There is no value (in my scenario) for
>   alerting the customer when an item has
>   been marked for shipping on our end.

In this schema, you search for a given item for a given user, and see if an item_workflow record exists for that item and the workflow state "Shipped".

Comment: interesting approach... but it does seem to add another layer of complexity... another consideration I failed to mention is that this table will be used to assess whether a member qualifies for shipments (based on how many he had in a month, and how many he is allowed per month, and how many items he currently has at home).. I'm not sure how it work out using an additional table to make those calcs

Comment: on a second note, I think you just clarified for me what my original question should have been.. it's hard to get clarity of mind some times without the nudge of an outside view!

Comment: @djacabson. I will accept this answer as it's works in this context, although I reposted the question. Thats for clearing this up for me.