# Using inheritance to solve a design problem

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling

I need a table that stores items and tracks when an item is...

1. queued
2. marked for shipping
3. shipped
4. marked for return
5. returned

The table also needs to tell me how many items a customer...

1. has received in a month
2. has at home at this time

I tried using inheritance. I assigned each step a `typeId` (from 1 to 5, each id representing the current step in the workflow). This approach is not ideal because updating a workflow step erases history.

For example, if an item moves from `shipped` (typeId 3) to `returned` (typeId 5) we lose an accurate count for shipped items.

How should I approach this? Also, I prefer to keep the data in one table unless I get a compelling reason not to.

**Update**

Items are mailed to customers incrementally. There are limits to how many items a customer can receive within a month period, and limits on how many items a customer can have at home at any given time. For this example, let's assume 4 for earlier and 2 for the latter. A customers queue can have any number of items. For this reason, items in the queue need to be ranked so the order of items sent can be according to the customers preference.

Items that have shipped already will need to fall out of ranking (the customer can no longer modify rank after an item is sent).

Comment: Just for the record, storing a type value is not inheritance. Inheritance involves creating classes/subclasses and inheriting members and data from other classes or objects. Perhaps I've misunderstood your explanation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969536/challenging-data-modeling-problem

Comment: @Catcall Flagged the other for deletion. I made a mess of the question and decided to ask again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No inheritance here. Time fields are actually date-time. A row is entered into the `Tracking` table when a customer adds an item to the queue. Other time columns from `TimeMarkedShip` to `TimeReturned` are `NULL` until the action happens. The `TimeQueued` is part of the primary key in order to allow a customer to rent an item more than once (sounds like video rentals to me).

[image]

To count items that a customer has at home you could use something like

```
select count(1)
from Tracking
where CustomerID = 1755
  and TimeShipped  is not NULL
  and TimeReturned is NULL ;
```

Comment: great example. Thank you. And you guessed right. There is one more required field: when a return label is created. When a customer marks an item for return, an employee will need to create a shipping label for it. Until then, the customer can change his mind.

Comment: another interesting twist is item rank... since customers will not receive all their items at once, rank needs to applied only for queued items... inheritance would have to be used then, no? Since items order shipped/processed fall out of the ranking requirement.

Comment: @Mohamad,  not sure I understand rank. Could you update the question with more detail and an example?

Comment: I updated the question. What I meant by rank is this: customers can't receive everything in their list at the same time. Items are sent incrementally, and there are limits on how many are sent in a month, and how many can be at a customers home at any given time. For this reason, items to need to have a rank column so the customer can set the priority of items (which get sent first when others are returned, for example).

Comment: @Mohamad, so a simple `QueuePriority` column would do. Sort out everything else on the business layer. A customer can enter any number for the `QueuePriority` -- higher priorities get shipped first.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a typeID for the current step, it looks like you need a boolean column for each step.  Then when you want to count the "net shipped" items, you can subtract the "returned" items from the "shipped" items.

In addition, if you want to track the history, you could make each of these steps a nullable date field, so that you can see that an item was shipped on 3/5/11 and returned on 4/1/11.  This may help if you're using this table in other ways, such as managing your shipping/receiving or billing.  A NULL, of course, would indicate that the step has not been performed (yet).